# Value of $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\prod_{k=1}^x\sin\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I had been preparing for a calculus test. After solving some limits problem , I tried to make my own limit problems. So , my question is if this limit exists or not ?$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\prod_{k=1}^x\sin\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)$$

I tried to apply L'hospital rule but it couldn't work because the derivative of numerator looks messy. Also , the logarithms do not seem to work. Online calculators like wolfram says that "insufficient time to determine limit". So , does this limit exists ? If yes , how can we find it's value ?

Comment: Assuming the limit is taken along positive integers $x$ (for otherwise the product does not make much sense), note that $$\left|x\prod_{k=1}^x\sin\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right|\leq x|\sin(1/x)\sin(2/x)|. $$ Now squeeze that limit!

Comment: @SangchulLee Hi sir , can you please hint me how that inequality follows ? I may be seeing it for first time. Thanks !

Comment: I forgot to mention that the above inequality holds only for $x=2,3,4,\ldots$. And this is obtained by utilizing a dumb bound $\left|\sin \theta\right|\leq 1$ which holds for all real $\theta$. Indeed, $$\left|x\prod_{k=1}^{x}\sin\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right|=x \cdot \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \cdot \left|\sin\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right| \cdot \prod_{k=3}^{x}\underbrace{\left|\sin\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right|}_{\leq 1}.$$

Comment: @An_Elephant The answer that is given along with my comments below it provides you with a solution. And as Sangchul Lee gives, you can do it directly without Stirling's Approximation as I suggested.

Comment: With that being said, it is a basic courtesy to upvote and accept answers which you have not done in many of your questions. It is the only way that you reward the time and effort the people took to answer your query. Even if you want your question to remain open for some personal reason, you can atleast upvote an answer. @An_Elephant

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I upvote after I read and understand an answer. I read the answer to this question yesterday but couldn't understand it fully. Now that I understand it , I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Out of my 52 questions asked , about 12 are un- answered , and 5 with un-accepted answers. Rest are with accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $x=\frac{1}{t}; t \to 0$

so we can rewrite the limit as
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{t}\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{1}{t}}{\sin{kt}}$$
$$=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}\prod_{k=2}^{\frac{1}{t}}\lim_{t \to 0}\sin{kt}$$
$$=0$$
we can separate the limits because they are all defined

so we get $1 \times 0 =0$

Comment: Might be a good idea to also include why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\sin(\frac{k}{n})\to 0$. It is this step that allows you to conclude that the limit of the product equals the product of the limits.

Comment: Spoiler for the op: $|\prod_{k=2}^{n}\sin(\frac{k}{n})|\leq \prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k}{n}=\frac{n!}{n^{n-1}}$ . Now one can apply Stirling's Approximation or several other ways to conclude that the limit is $0$